# Ignore case switch and caret not working with grep as expected

Tags: grep, osx-lion

Given the following file:

```
this is some words
and this one too<div>
<html></html>
and more words 123
Caps to begin
ASDFSDFSDF
```

the following 2 commands work as I would expect:

```
grep -i '[:alpha:]' testfile
```

gives

```
this is some words
and this one too<div>
<html></html>
and more words 123
Caps to begin
ASDFSDFSDF
```

and

```
grep '[:alpha:]' testfile
```

gives

```
this is some words
and this one too<div>
<html></html>
and more words 123
Caps to begin
```

but

```
grep '^[:alpha:]' testfile

and this one too<div>
and more words 123
```

and

```
grep -i '^[:alpha:]' testfile

and this one too<div>
and more words 123
ASDFSDFSDF
```

The caret which should ensure the line begins with an alphanumeric has messed everything up. Why is the 'this is some words' line and the 'Caps to begin' line not getting matched?
This is using bash on Mac Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
grep '^[[:alpha:]]' testfile
grep -i '^[[:alpha:]]' testfile
```

Comment: ah yes. I was confusing the syntaxes `'[[:alpha:]]'` and `'[a-z]'`. Grep and tiredness don't mix well..